# how do i rotate a HTML 3D scene?

Tags: html, css, animation, 3d, rotation

*i want to make a 3d scene made out of squares and then move around without addons*

then i started by watching a video about html and 3d graphics, i made this and i have been stuck for 2 days trying to animate the scene, i have tried with javascript to detect the mouse or keyboard but im unable to make it work, **im new to css, html and java**

i use visual studio code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>engine 1A</title>
        <style>
                html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
                body {background: black; overflow: hidden;}

                #scene
                {
                    perspective: 800px;
                    transition-duration: 5s;
                    transition-delay: 2s;
                    transition-timing-function: linear;
                    transition-property: width;
                }
                @keyframes roll {
                        from {
                            transform:rotateX(0) rotateY(0);
                            }

                        to {
                            transform:rotateX(360) rotateY(360);
                            }
                        }
                #mainD
                {
                    width: 500px;
                    height: 500px;
                    margin: 200px auto;
                }

                #boxD
                {
                    width: 500px;
                    height: 500px;
                }

                #boxD div
                {
                    position: absolute;
                    border: 1px solid white;
                    width: 500px;
                    height: 500px;
                    transform-style: preserve-3d;
                }
                
                #ZB
                {
                    transform: translateZ(250px) rotateY(180deg)
                }
                #ZP
                {
                    transform: translateZ(-250px)
                }
                #XB
                {
                    transform: translateX(-250px) rotateY(90deg)
                }
                #XP
                {
                    transform: translateX(250px) rotateY(-90deg)
                }
                #YB
                {
                    transform: translateY(-250px) rotateX(90deg)
                }
                #YP
                {
                    transform: translateY(250px) rotateX(-90deg)
                }
                
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="scene">
            <div id="mainD">
                <div id="boxD">
                    <div id="ZB"></div>
                    <div id="ZP"></div>
                    <div id="XP"></div>
                    <div id="XB"></div>
                    <div id="YP"></div>
                    <div id="YB"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: Are you trying to animate the scene in some way automatically or are you wanting to do something when the user say does a mousedown and move?  What do you want the effect to be? What JS have you tried?

Comment: im trying it to be when the user says, but i have been trying automatic for the test

i have tried what the guy on this video types at 7:52 https://youtu.be/kIv8DtVpA9s?t=472